# Find the number of files that contains specific attributes assigned to more than one element

Tags: xml, xpath

Need a count on the number of files that contain

```
//SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY@AUTH="M" 
//SIGNOFF/INSPBY@AUTH="I"
```

Input XML:

```
 <SIGNOFF ID="S0001">
    <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" AUTH="M"/>
    <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" AUTH="I"/>
 </SIGNOFF>
```

Been playing around with something like this...

```
//SIGNOFF/ACCOMPBY[contains (@AUTH, 'M')]/INSPBY[contains (@AUTH, 'I')]/ancestor::TASKCARD/@CARDNBR/concat("",.)
```

Thanks so much for any point in the right direction!

Comment: Please explain what that `concat()` part is about (which, by the way, will only work in XPath 2.0 since it's a function as an axis step).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but I'll give it a try. Assuming a more sensible input document (more sensible in the sense of containing both positive and negative examples):

```
<root>
<SIGNOFF ID="YES">
    <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" AUTH="M"/>
    <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" AUTH="I"/>
 </SIGNOFF>
<SIGNOFF ID="NO">
    <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" AUTH="OTHER"/>
    <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" AUTH="I"/>
</SIGNOFF>
<SIGNOFF ID="NO">
    <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" AUTH="M"/>
    <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" AUTH="OTHER"/>
</SIGNOFF>
</root>
```

You could use the following XPath expression:

```
//SIGNOFF[ACCOMPBY/@AUTH = 'M' and INSPBY/@AUTH = 'I']
```

which would yield only one result, a `SIGNOFF` element:

```
<SIGNOFF ID="YES">
  <ACCOMPBY ID="JCAT0001" AUTH="M"/>
  <INSPBY ID="JCIT0001" AUTH="I"/>
</SIGNOFF>
```

Comment: The expression and example you gave is very helpful!  Thank you so much for your time... :)